# Re-running code after an exception

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I have some Python code that I am using for web scraping off a https website using the following code:

```
 for i in range (0, number):
 html = s.get(web_address[i], verify=False, headers=headers)
 ....more unrelated code
```

Currently I am getting an intermittent error every 1000 links or so from the s.get command [part of the request library], that doesn't replicate - if I re-run the exact same code with the exact same link immediately afterwards, it works correctly.

For reference, the error-lines I am getting are:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 469, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 457, in request
   resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 569, in send
   r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
```

I am not too concerned about fixing the underlying problem (... may be something to do with the server I am connecting to just occasionally behaving odd/inconsistent) - I just want the "s.get" code to try-again if there is an error, rather than exiting the python code. Ideally looking to attempt the s.get command up to 3x per link, and then if still getting error, exit the for loop at that point, and move on to next item in the for loop (...but if i continue to get errors for 10 different links, then to exit the whole program...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your save key is in the domain of [catching exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).
In general, you should use something like:

```
   while True:
     try:
       # Your code
     except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
       pass
```

If you need to continue to run your script after appearing of multiple exceptions - use tuples, i.e. your line with `except` should look like `except (request.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.TimeoutError)`.